# How to configure Nginx to serve Wordpress in Symfony2 web directory

Tags: wordpress, symfony, nginx

I have a Symfony2 project and I want to add a WordPress blog in /web/blog directory.

I need to know how can I configure the virtualhost to run both. My current configuration is:

```html
server {

    listen 80;
    server_name my-project.local;
    root /var/www/my-project/web;

    location / {
       # try to serve file directly, fallback to app.php
       try_files $uri /app.php$is_args$args;
    }

    # DEV
    location ~ ^/(app_dev|config)\.php(/|$) {
       fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
       fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.*)$;
       include fastcgi_params;
       fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
       fastcgi_param HTTPS on;
    }

    # PROD
    location ~ ^/app\.php(/|$) {
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.*)$;
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_param HTTPS off;

        # Prevents URIs that include the front controller. This will 404:
        # http://domain.tld/app.php/some-path
        # Remove the internal directive to allow URIs like this
        internal;
    }

  error_log /var/log/nginx/protox_error.log;
  access_log /var/log/nginx/protox_access.log;
}
```

Can you help me?